# How to write zero byte to file in Android?

Tags: android, file

I am creating an app that helps user to hide secret files like text file or photos. If user is going to delete the secret files, I want to make sure the files deleted is unrecoverable. I am trying to write zero byte or zero write the file before deleting. The problem is it doesn't zero write the file, it doesn't do anything. This is what I currently have.

```
public void zeroWriteDelete(File file) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream1 = new FileOutputStream(file);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];

    int read;
    while((read = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
        Arrays.fill(buffer, (byte)0);
        fileOutputStream1.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    fileOutputStream1.flush();
    fileOutputStream1.close();
    fileInputStream.close();
}
```

So, how do I zero write or overwrite the file with zero byte or data ? Or maybe other ways to make sure the deleted file is unrecoverable ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read from the file, or zero the buffer:

```
public void zeroWriteDelete(File file) throws IOException{
    long length = file.length();
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];

    for (long i = 0; i < length; i += buffer.length) {
        raf.write(buffer, 0, (int)Math.min(buffer.length, length-i));
    }
    raf.close();
    file.delete(); // you forgot this rather vital part
}
```

E&OE

Comment: I used this code and tried on some image files in android phone. The photo can still be viewed properly but when I pull it out to the PC the image cannot be shown. So, I assumed that the code does work. I think it need to refresh the edited file, is there a way to refresh the file ? I didn't put in the delete method because I want to make sure the file is overwritten with random stuff.

Comment: Define 'refresh'. It should be self-evident that this code zeros the file.

Comment: yup it zeros the file. Lets say I zeros a picture, normally it should not display the original content but in my case the picture is still viewable using the gallery app. So 'refresh' mean update the picture file with the recent changes.